# Why does the NativeScript CLI command 'tns devices' just hang?

Tags: nativescript

e.g.

```
tns devices android
```

Gives me:

```
C:\Users\Matthew>tns devices android
Connected devices & emulators
Searching for devices...
[hangs here till I Ctrl+C]
Cannot find connected devices. Reconnect any connected devices, verify     that your system recognizes them, and run this command again.
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

My device is visible in windows, a HTC One M9, and the drivers for it are installed. The device is in 'dev' mode and the USB debugging is switching on, and shows up as a warning notication.

SideKick shows no connected devices either. Although I suspect it's using the same back end that the tns command uses.

'tns doctor' says everything is good. I can build apps locally.

Comment: The command `tns devices` (for Android) is basically using `adb devices` which is the native command. Run `adb devices` to see if you are able to see any connected and active devices attached. If not, then you should reconnect the device(try different cable as strangely enough some fake cables are not working with ADB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a number of active adb.exe processes. And it seems they were in a bad state somehow. Closing any one of them didn't result in progress but if I closed the whole process tree with [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) then:

```
adb devices
```

Would actually list without hanging.